Organizational Chart without using Library
I have working half organization chart, I am struggling with making sure connectors are nicely connecting and moving with nodes when they are expanded or the node tree is growing/grown size. I need help with the calculations for proper lines connectors.
My idea is to utilize the calc method and but the formula i am not sure about. Image attached with broken lines is the one without the calc method changes.
        // Update CSS custom property for line calculations
        container.style.setProperty('--first-child-offset', `${firstChildCenter}px`);
        container.style.setProperty('--last-child-offset', `${lastChildCenter}px`);

I did this changes on the DOM inspect mode first container(app-chart-node)
--first-child-offset: calc(18% - 7px); --last-child-offset: calc(83% - 10px); second(inner children from a child). --first-child-offset: calc(30% - 7px); --last-child-offset: calc(73% - 7px); 

HTML code
<div class="org-node-container">
      <div
        class="org-node"
        [class.expanded]="orgChartService.isNodeExpanded(node.id)"
      >
        <div class="node-content">
          <div class="node-info">
            <div class="node-name">{{ node.name }}</div>
            <div class="node-title" *ngIf="node.title">{{ node.title }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <button
          *ngIf="node.children?.length"
          class="toggle-btn"
          (click)="toggleNode($event)"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="orgChartService.isNodeExpanded(node.id)"
          [attr.aria-label]="
            orgChartService.isNodeExpanded(node.id) ? 'Collapse' : 'Expand'
          "
        >
          <span class="toggle-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div
        *ngIf="node.children?.length && orgChartService.isNodeExpanded(node.id)"
        class="children-container"
        [class.single-child]="node.children && node.children.length === 1"
        [attr.data-children]="node.children && node.children.length"
        #childrenContainer
      >
        <claude-node
          *ngFor="
            let child of node.children;
            let first = first;
            let last = last
          "
          [node]="child"
          [level]="level + 1"
          [class.first-child]="first"
          [class.last-child]="last"
        >
        </claude-node>
      </div>
    </div>

TS
private updateChildrenLines() {
    const container = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.children-container');
    if (!container || !this.node.children) return;

    // Handle single child case
    if (this.node.children.length === 1) {
      container.classList.add('single-child');
      return;
    }

    container.classList.remove('single-child');

    // Update the container's width to ensure proper line rendering
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      const children = container.querySelectorAll('claude-node');
      if (children.length >= 2) {
        const firstChild = children[0] as HTMLElement;
        const lastChild = children[children.length - 1] as HTMLElement;

        // Calculate the actual width needed based on the children's positions
        const containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
        const firstChildCenter = firstChild.offsetLeft + (firstChild.offsetWidth / 2);
        const lastChildCenter = lastChild.offsetLeft + (lastChild.offsetWidth / 2);

        // Update CSS custom property for line calculations
        container.style.setProperty('--first-child-offset', `${firstChildCenter}px`);
        container.style.setProperty('--last-child-offset', `${lastChildCenter}px`);

        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }
    });
  }

CSS
.org-node-container {
  --node-min-width: 200px;
  --node-padding: 16px;
  --node-margin: 24px;
  --line-color: #ccc;
  --line-thickness: 2px;
  --transition-duration: 0.3s;
  --horizontal-line-width: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 var(--node-margin);
}

/* Remove vertical line above parent */
.org-node-container:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.org-node {
  position: relative;
  min-width: var(--node-min-width);
  margin: var(--node-margin) 10px 0 0;
  transition: all var(--transition-duration) ease;
}

.node-content {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: var(--node-padding);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: all var(--transition-duration) ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.node-content:hover {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.children-container {
  --first-child-offset: 0px;
  --last-child-offset: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: var(--node-margin);
  transition: all var(--transition-duration) ease;
  /* gap: 20px; */
  column-gap: 20px;
}

/* Vertical line from parent to horizontal line */
.children-container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: var(--line-thickness);
  height: var(--node-margin);
  background: var(--line-color);
}

/* Horizontal line between children */
/* .children-container:not(.single-child)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--node-margin);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: var(--line-thickness);
  background: var(--line-color);
  Calculate width based on first and last child position
  left: calc(var(--first-child-offset) - var(--node-margin));
  width: calc(var(--last-child-offset) - var(--first-child-offset) + (2 * var(--node-margin)));
  margin: 0 auto;
} */
.children-container:not(.single-child)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--node-margin);
  left: calc(var(--first-child-offset) - var(--node-margin));
  width: calc(var(--last-child-offset) - var(--first-child-offset) + (2 * var(--node-margin)));
  height: var(--line-thickness);
  background: var(--line-color);
}

.children-container claude-node {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: calc(var(--node-min-width) + 2 * var(--node-margin));
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Vertical lines from horizontal line to children */
.children-container claude-node::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: var(--line-thickness);
  height: var(--node-margin);
  background: var(--line-color);
}

/* Node info styles */
.node-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 4px;
}

.node-name {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.node-title {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  color: #666;
}

/* Toggle button styles */
.toggle-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 53%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all var(--transition-duration) ease;
}

.toggle-btn:hover {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.toggle-btn .toggle-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border: solid #666;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  transition: transform var(--transition-duration) ease;
}

.org-node.expanded .toggle-icon {
  transform: translate(-50%, -25%) rotate(-135deg);
}

I do not want to use chart libraries, so I tried couple of CSS properties but I can't seem to find the right connections and missing the formulas to calculate and manage the lines dynamically.
I will appreciate any help and thank you.
For Demonstraion
